# how to set text size of listview item in c# ( windows forms)?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0

how to set text size of listview item in c# ( windows forms)?
ListViewItem of LIstView control is displaying only upto 259 characters? why

Is it possible to insert more than 259 characters to a listviewitem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 259 limit is by design...(I guess because the ListView was originally designed for showing lists of files, etc - so the limit probably comes from the file system's MAX_PATH limitation - I don't know...just a guess!?).

The item does store the full text though - it's just truncated for display.  So you should be able to override it to display the full text, or maybe find another way to show the full information in your UI like the suggestion here...

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;321104

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to handle your own rendering of items to do that. Inherit from a ListView, hook up to the draw item event, and manually render your ListViewItems.

Comment: Why it it limited to 259 characters only?

Comment: For layout purposes I imagine. I manually render items to change their behaviour and its very difficult to get them to render correctly with long strings. They tend to draw on top of each other, somewhere some layout algorithm probably needs overriding too, but I never found that.

Comment: Pure rubbish. Apple's NSTableView has never had that problem - for an API that is over a decade old. Sounds more MS had issues with displaying more than 259 characters and made the users suffer for it. This is 2014, not 1988.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are limited to a certain number of characters. Instead, add a tooltip there. Whenever the user hovers the listview item, even if the text is truncated with elipsis, the tooltip will display all text.

Comment: True. Read the msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.text%28v=VS.100%29.aspx "The text to display for the item. This should not exceed 259 characters."

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply ! Do u knw hw to insert text having more than 259 characters?

Comment: I think you heavnt answerd his qs. He wants to explicitly set a MAX value for the text it can display, perhaps 50 chars or some thing i thing.